# How to filter for string in newsbeuter then move to folder?

Tags: rss, push, feed

I have 700 news feeds that I need to scan for the keyword/string "Linux" occurring in either title or the content of each new post.

I found how to filter in the docs
[news docs](http://synflood.at/newsbeuter/newsbeuter.html#id2506445)

```
( title =~ "Linux" or content =~ "Linux" )
```

but I cannot find any indication of how to go the next step and push the message into another folder.

If possible, I am trying to work within the newsbeuter system because right now it opens up firefox perfectly for urls, I just want to avoid scrolling 700 folders.

config:

```
use-proxy yes
proxy yoda.server.com:3128
browser firefox
```

How do you filter and move and post based on string in newsbeuter?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, Newsbeuter doesn't support any kind of mass-refiling ([yet](https://github.com/akrennmair/newsbeuter/issues/235)), so what you're asking for can't be done.